# How can I find and delete duplicate cells in 1 row?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a lot of row which has to be edited. I want to use VBA for it, but I don't know a way how to find and delete the duplicates between a row.

For example I want to turn this:

```
00122 | Gilera | DNA | DNA | Runner | VXR | Runner | FXR | 180 | 50 | 125 | 50
```

Into this

```
00122 | Gilera | DNA | Runner | VXR | FXR | 180 | 50 | 125
```

Do someone knows a way how to do this?
 Best regards!

Comment: look at using a scripting dictionary, to go across, adding to the dic, but before, checking its not there using dic.Exists(x)

Comment: `for intRow=1 to lastRow:for intCol=1 to lastCol:if not dic.Exists(cells(intRow,intCol).value dic.add(cells(intRow,intCol)):next intCol:next intRow`   this is just an example of an approach, not tested.  You would need to split the string, and use that way.  I'll put something on in a sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Function testDupes(strInput As String, strDelimiter As String) As String

Dim intRow As Integer
Dim intCol As Integer
Dim arrSplit() As String
Dim dicCompare As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim intCounter As Integer

arrSplit = Split(strInput, strDelimiter)

For intCounter = 0 To UBound(arrSplit)

    If Not dicCompare.Exists(CStr(arrSplit(intCounter))) Then
        dicCompare.Add CStr(arrSplit(intCounter)), CStr(arrSplit(intCounter))
    End If

Next intCounter

For intCounter = 0 To dicCompare.Count - 1
    testDupes = testDupes & dicCompare.Keys()(intCounter) & _
        IIf(intCounter < dicCompare.Count, strDelimiter, "")
Next intCounter

Set dicCompare = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: This uses Split, to break the string, then we iterate the array, using the dictionary object to check for dupes, then rebuild back to string

Comment: Great! but how can I use this function?

Comment: serious? range("b1")=testDupes(range("a1"),"|")   think you need to have a look at how VBA works also.

Comment: A sorry, excuse me! But anyway, I have a problem when I call it. The problem shows up in this line;
`Dim dicCompare As New Scripting.Dictionary`
VBA showes the following popup; **a data type defined by the user is not defined**

Comment: You need to add the scripting.runtime reference to the code.

Comment: No probs, glad to be of help.